# Can you utilize Worksheetfunction. sumifs to sum values based on multiple conditions in THE SAME column? (VBA)

Tags: vba

I am trying to summarise production demands on different machines based on multiple article numbers within a dataset. When I only look for 1 value in 1 column with worksheetfunction.sumifs, everything runs smoothly. However, when I try to use an array or variable to look at several article numbers within the same column, I get Run-Time error "13". When I do the same thing as just an excel formula, everything runs smoothly. It is when I try to do it as an array in vba as I run into problems.

I can do the sumifs as separate lines of code for separate article numbers and add them together (with a "+" ). However as I have several article numbers that are being added together, this will take both alot of space and time....

So basically, my general question before posting the code is: is it possible to run Worksheetfunction.sumifs to sum values based on multiple conditions in THE SAME column? And if yes, How?

I have been trying to get passed this error for days now and it is getting really annoying, so I would be very happy for help :D

Comment: Seems like you've been using SUMIFS instead of VLOOKUP, and now you want [DSUM](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dsum-function-53181285-0c4b-4f5a-aaa3-529a322be41b).

Comment: `=SUMIFS(B1:B5,A1:A5,{"A","B"})` would return two values - the sum of A's and B's.  Wrap it in a `SUM` to get a A's+B's:  `=SUM(SUMIFS(B1:B5,A1:A5,{"A","B"}))`